# PHP Doctrine and Adhoc SQL Queries

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

We have loads of adhoc queries filling up DB cache (100,000+), is there a setting in doctrine to force it to prepare statements binded to parameters, so SQL plans can be cached and reused? We use PDO to interface with the DB. It seems the parameter binding are not being passed onto SQL but rather passed as literals? I know doctrine is supposed to bind params but does it tell the DB that it has ?